# Как надо улучшить jQuery, чтоб класс, который мы вещаем, не пропал после перезагрузки страницы?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Добрый день, у меня на странице есть несколько ненумерованных списков такого вида:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="">Ссылка1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Ссылка2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Ссылка3</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Ссылка4</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Ссылка5</a></li>
</ul>
```

При нажатии на ссылку я проверяю с помощью jQuery есть ли у элемента li class active, если нет, то вешаю его.

Но проблема в том, что при нажатии на ссылку класс вещается на li, сразу же идет перезагрузка страницы, так как в li лежит тег a и естественно класс active пропадает. Как надо улучшить код jQuery, чтобы класс не пропадал после перезагрузки страницы?

Вот jQuery код:

```
$(function() {
                $("ul li").on('click', function(e){
                    var $this = $(this);
                    if(!$this.hasClass('active')){
                        $this.addClass("active");
                    }
                    console.log($(this));
                });
            });
```

Comment: вот вы уже давно этим занимаетесь, ну почему бы не взять и не изучить самые основы веб программирования? Короткий ответ - **никак** ваш код сгенерен на сервере, вот в  нем class active и добавляйте. можете конечно еще в local storage/куках хранить активный элемент (как нить его пометить там или что...)

Comment: >вот вы уже давно этим занимаетесь, ну почему бы не взять и не изучить самые основы веб программирования?

а зачем учиться, если можно спросить?)

Comment: @eicto Ответ никак - не правильный. Написал решение проблемы ниже... Так что Вы зря минусовали...

Comment: @eprivalov1 у вас в вопросе нет url в href, в случае url конечно можно так.

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                $('a[href="' + this.location.pathname + '"]').parent().addClass('active');
             });
```

Comment: а можно было еще напрямую в css заинжектить, вот это был бы шик